# email differant person depending on select option in form

Tags: php, forms, email, header, switch-statement

i trying to make a form that emails someone different depending on what is selected on the form. when i submit the form i just get a blank page with the url pointing to "../wp-content/test/test.php" it wont even go to the default oops page. im not sure what im doing wrong. any input appreciated. everything worked fine until i added the switch. i can sent an email to just one person for all option just fine. here is my form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="../wp-content/test/test.php">




 <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

<select id="club" name="club">
  <option name="wordone" value="wordone">wordone</option>
  <option name="wordtwo" value="wordtwo">wordtwo</option>
</select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>
```

this is my php:

```
   <?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $club = $_POST['club'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $email_subject = 'New Form submission';
    $email_body = '...';
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_from \r\n";
switch($_POST['club']){
case 'wordone':
    $to = "nick@website.com";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header('Location: http://website.com/thanks2');
break;
case 'wordtwo':
    $to = "chris@website.com";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header('Location: http://website.com/thanks1');
break;
default:
    header('Location: http://website.com/oops');

}
}
```

Comment: the form doesn't have fields for `name` or `email` ~ or are these omitted just in the question? There also seems to be lots of duplication of code which could/should be condensed. The line `'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` is also wrong - it doesn't seem to be part of anything

Comment: As @RamRaider says, the line `'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` is causing you issues most likely, it's a random string and needs to be assigned to a variable. It also sounds like you need to turn on error reporting, as you should be getting some kind of error message.

Comment: yeah i did remove the name and email part from my post. i just edited my original post to show it. i figured it was the ($_POST['club']) part causing the problem. i also removed 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); from my source idk what that is it was just included in some code i copied.

Comment: everything worked fine as far as sending emails goes until i added the switch part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that the original question has been edited to remove the offending pieces of code mentioned earlier it is still not obvious as to why the code is failing but perhaps the following, condensed code, might be of use.

The only thing I can see is that you test explicitly for `$_POST['Submit']` but the submit button does not have a name.

```
<?php
    /* check that all expected POST variables are present */
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['club'], $_POST['email'] ) ){

        /* set POST variables as named vars for convenience */
        $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
        $club = trim( $_POST['club'] );
        $email= trim( $_POST['email'] );

        $php=phpversion();
        $default = false;

        /* do these change on a person by person user or stay the same? */
        $subject = 'New Form submission';
        $body = '...';


        switch( $club ){
            case 'wordone':
                $to = "chris@website.com";
                $redirect='http://website.com/thanks1';
            break;

            case 'wordtwo':
                $to = "nick@website.com";
                $redirect='http://website.com/thanks2';
            break;

            default:
                $default=true;
                $result=false;
                $redirect='http://website.com/oops';
            break;
        }


        /* send the email */
        if( !$default ){
            $headers = "From: {$email}\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: {$email}\r\n";
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/{$php}\r\n";
            $result=@mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );            
        }

        /* redirect */
        header( 'Location: '.$redirect.'?mailsent='.$result );
    }
?>



<form name="contactform" method="post" action="../wp-content/test/test.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
    <!-- no need for the `name` attribute in an `option` and they can remain unclosed like this -->
    <select id="club" name="club">
        <option value="wordone">wordone
        <option value="wordtwo">wordtwo
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit">  
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much. was driving me crazy. this worked perfect.

Comment: glad it help you get it sorted!